# Creating a uniqe id next to the id of each entity in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have entities like payment, user, order,... in my system

My database is Mysql and all the data has a unique and non-repeating id

For example, suppose I want to update the information of an order with id 2565 .
Naturally, I should send my request to the following api :

> PATCH : http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/orders/2565

Well, if I want to do my operations with id, it is not a good thing in terms of security.

Because the user can get the order number or try other identifiers easily and...

I want to have another field called uniqeid next to id. I want my e-field to be numeric and non-repeating and 10 digits.

What is the best way to meet this need of mine?

For example, when creating an order, I did the following. But the output I got was not what I wanted and I am looking for a better way

> App\Models\Order.php

```
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::creating(function ($payment) {
            $payment->unique_id = uniqid();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362930/generate-a-random-10-digit-number-and-insert-into-mysql any use (and if not why - this helps suggesting further solutions)

Comment: I would suggest `$payment->unique_id = time()`;

Comment: You can have a uuid v4 with `Str::uuid()` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/strings#method-str-uuid).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you are required to store the unique identifier in the database, but another approach would be using [Sqids (previously known as Hashids)](https://sqids.org/php). It will encode/decode your incrementing ID to a more obscure string.